# sqlite issue with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, heroku

I was using sqlite gem for my rails project, and since I had to put the app on Heroku, and Heroku doesn't support sqlite, I added **pg** gem to my Gemfile.

```
 gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
```

But now I am not able to run the project locally on my machine.

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

I am getting this.

Please help.

Comment: Please post your `Gemfile`

Comment: @Suraj: Please refer my answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846779/not-able-to-create-staging-instance-on-heroku/30847128#30847128.

Comment: @Suraj: Hope this will work for you.

Comment: There's some syntax issue here in your answer when I am putting this in the Gemfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
>   Add gem 'sqlite3' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the
>   minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Add `gem 'sqlite3', group: :development` to your `Gemfile` and do `bundle install`.

And also you should be putting `pg gem` in a **production group** like this for you to avoid further conflicts in local

```
#Gemfile
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.17.1'
end
```

***OR***

```
gem 'pg', '0.17.1', group: :production
```

***AND***

```
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
```

***Update #1***

And also, you should edit your `database.yml` to specify **different adapters** for `development` and `production` like this

```
#database.yml
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: your_db
  username: your_username
  password: your_pass
  -----
  -----

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: your_production_db
  username: your_production_username
  password: your_production_pass
  ------
  ------
```

***Update #2***

> FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

If you set a ***password based authentication***, then you need to do below steps

1.Open the file `pg_hba.conf` for Ubuntu it will be in `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main` and change the this line:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

2.Restart the server

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

3.Login into ***psql*** and set your password

```
psql -U postgres

ALTER USER postgres with password 'your-pass'; #as in your database.yml
```

Comment: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres" getting this. 


getting this issue

Comment: Now I get password authentication failed issue :/

Comment: @Suraj You have set the same password in the `database.yml` file too

Comment: It is same..
psql -U postgres  After this it asks me password when I put the same password I get the above issue..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80628/discussion-between-pavan-and-suraj).

Answer (score 0):

In your database.yml, change adapter: sqlite3 to adapter: postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `gem 'sqlite'` with `gem 'pg'` in your gemfile.

delete your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle update`

then, paste the following in your config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: nameofyourapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: discuss_test
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: password
```

replace the username and password as per your configuration. For mine, username is `postgres` and password `1234`.

Heroku does not need you to define production settings in the database.yml. It will be auto configured once you push your app.

If you are getting `FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`

The problem is in your `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf` file. This line:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Should be

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

You'll need to reload your postgresql service after changing this `/etc/init.d/postgresql reload`

Comment: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"


getting this.